# Characterization of geodesic balls

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-analysis

In $\mathbb R^{n\geq3}$, spheres can be characterized by single layer potentials having constant eigenfunction. More precisely we have the following:

**Theorem ([H. Shahgholian](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-115-04/S0002-9939-1992-1162956-7/))** Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^{n\geq3}$ be a bounded smooth domain and for some $c>0$

$$\int_{\partial\Omega}\frac{1}{\|x-y\|^{n-2}}ds_x=\frac{c}{\|y\|^{n-2}},\,\,\forall y\not\in\bar{\Omega}$$
Then $\partial\Omega$ is a sphere centered at the origin. (here $ds$ represents the surface area).

Are there generalization of this statement for Riemannian manifolds and geodesic balls?

Comment: Have you tried working this out for spherically symmetric Riemannian manifolds with $\Omega$ some geodesic ball about the center? What are the results?

Comment: @WillieWong  That seems like a great point to start. Currently, I am trying to see if the proof in Shagholian's can be adapted  to  $\mathbb S^n$.